# Are any of the GWT widget libraries compatible with uiBinder?

Tags: gwt, widget, smartgwt, gwt-ext

Are any of the third-party widget libraries compatible with GWT 2.0's features, including uiBinder?  All I know is that it seems as if SmartGWT can't.

Answer (score 0):

SmartGWT - well SmartClient actually - has its own mechanisms that do the same thing as uiBinder; it's likely more advanced than uiBinder itself.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd prefer a library that complies with vanilla GWT.

Comment: Can I use SmartGWT with UIBinder? Now I have a project on GWT with UIBinder and I need to integrate SmartGWT into it. Can you explain to me how can I do this?